# CRM 2016 Plugin Fails with Error : Plugin data is corrupted or too large - Notes

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am developing a plugin for a CRM 2016 On Premise implementation.

The max file size setting has been set to 30,000 KB in Administration -> system settings -> Email tab.

I have a plugin which runs asynchronously on post create of notes.

The plugin checks if the note has an attachment and if the attachment is present, it gets the attachment and uploads it to sharepoint.

I have been able to load notes with attachments of up to 16 MB successfully through the plugin.

However, when I create a note with an attachment of size 20 MB, I async plugin fails with the following error:

Bad Data: Plugin data is corrupted or too large.

I read the attribute into a byte array using the ConvertToBase64 message on the documentbody attribute of the note.

Can anyone help me with the issue or suggest some approaches I can try out to troubleshoot and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you're going to find a solution with the plugin, but another way I might suggest is a notification and pull type model.  You notify another application/service of a note with an attachment, it then queries and pulls the attachment to puts it into SharePoint.

This takes data copy operations off the async service which you could potentially put under great strain with a plugin doing data copy and effect your system in a very negative manner.

If this was CRM Online I might use a service bus queue sending all note/annotation create messages, process that queue with a logic app, process the queue item and determine if it has an attachment and have it execute an Azure function to put it in SharePoint.  There is a SharePoint connector in logic apps I am just not sure you can get note and pass the attachment to SharePoint just through configuration of the logic app.

You could potentially also just poll the notes for the delta changes (creates) at a certain interval too instead of the notification/queue.